# How to display Flushbar from login api error in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flushbar

I have a login system working with Flutter, PHP, and SQL but I want to be able to display the errors (if any) as a Flushbar. The controller receives the error as `(res["message"])` and i would like this to be displayed on the register page but i cant seem to get it to work

Here is the controller that is called on click

```
  void register() async {
    try {
      var response = await http
          .post(Uri.parse("http://noddospls/untitled/authentication/register.php"), body: {
        "name"    : nameTE.text,
        "username": emailTE.text,
        "password": passwordTE.text
      });
      print(response.body);
      var res = json.decode(response.body);
      var success = (res["success"]);
      print (success);
      if (formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
        if (success == "false"){
          //display error from api (res["message"])
        } else if (success == "true") {
          Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).push(
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => LogInScreen(),
            ),
          );
        }
      }
    }catch(e){
      print(e);
    }
  }
```

and here is my page that the controller is called from

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FxBuilder<RegisterController>(
        controller: controller,
        builder: (controller) {
          return Scaffold(
            body: Padding(
              padding: FxSpacing.fromLTRB(
                  20, FxSpacing.safeAreaTop(context) + 20, 20, 20),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  FxText.h3(
                    'Sign up',
                    fontWeight: 700,
                  ),
                  FxSpacing.height(20),
                  Form(
                    key: controller.formKey,
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        TextFormField(
                          style: FxTextStyle.b2(),
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                              floatingLabelBehavior:
                                  FloatingLabelBehavior.never,
                              filled: true,
                              isDense: true,
                              fillColor: customTheme.card,
                              prefixIcon: Icon(
                                FeatherIcons.user,
                                color: theme.colorScheme.onBackground,
                              ),
                              hintText: "Name",
                              enabledBorder: outlineInputBorder,
                              focusedBorder: outlineInputBorder,
                              border: outlineInputBorder,
                              contentPadding: FxSpacing.all(16),
                              hintStyle: FxTextStyle.b2(),
                              isCollapsed: true),
                          maxLines: 1,
                          controller: controller.nameTE,
                          validator: controller.validateName,
                          cursorColor: theme.colorScheme.onBackground,
                        ),
                        FxSpacing.height(20),
                        TextFormField(
                          style: FxTextStyle.b2(),
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                              floatingLabelBehavior:
                                  FloatingLabelBehavior.never,
                              filled: true,
                              isDense: true,
                              fillColor: customTheme.card,
                              prefixIcon: Icon(
                                FeatherIcons.mail,
                                color: theme.colorScheme.onBackground,
                              ),
                              hintText: "Email Address",
                              enabledBorder: outlineInputBorder,
                              focusedBorder: outlineInputBorder,
                              border: outlineInputBorder,
                              contentPadding: FxSpacing.all(16),
                              hintStyle: FxTextStyle.b2(),
                              isCollapsed: true),
                          maxLines: 1,
                          controller: controller.emailTE,
                          validator: controller.validateEmail,
                          cursorColor: theme.colorScheme.onBackground,
                        ),
                        FxSpacing.height(20),
                        TextFormField(
                          style: FxTextStyle.b2(),
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                              floatingLabelBehavior:
                                  FloatingLabelBehavior.never,
                              filled: true,
                              isDense: true,
                              fillColor: customTheme.card,
                              prefixIcon: Icon(
                                FeatherIcons.lock,
                                color: theme.colorScheme.onBackground,
                              ),
                              hintText: "Password",
                              enabledBorder: outlineInputBorder,
                              focusedBorder: outlineInputBorder,
                              border: outlineInputBorder,
                              contentPadding: FxSpacing.all(16),
                              hintStyle: FxTextStyle.b2(),
                              isCollapsed: true),
                          maxLines: 1,
                          controller: controller.passwordTE,
                          validator: controller.validatePassword,
                          cursorColor: theme.colorScheme.onBackground,
                        ),
                        FxSpacing.height(20),
                        TextFormField(
                          style: FxTextStyle.b2(),
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                              floatingLabelBehavior:
                              FloatingLabelBehavior.never,
                              filled: true,
                              isDense: true,
                              fillColor: customTheme.card,
                              prefixIcon: Icon(
                                FeatherIcons.lock,
                                color: theme.colorScheme.onBackground,
                              ),
                              hintText: "Re-type Password",
                              enabledBorder: outlineInputBorder,
                              focusedBorder: outlineInputBorder,
                              border: outlineInputBorder,
                              contentPadding: FxSpacing.all(16),
                              hintStyle: FxTextStyle.b2(),
                              isCollapsed: true),
                          maxLines: 1,
                          controller: controller.password2TE,
                          validator: controller.validatePassword,
                          cursorColor: theme.colorScheme.onBackground,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  FxSpacing.height(24),
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      FxText.b3(
                        'By Signing up, you agree to our ',
                        fontSize: 11,
                      ),
                      FxText.b3(
                        'Terms & Conditions',
                        color: customTheme.fitnessPrimary,
                        fontSize: 11,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  FxSpacing.height(24),
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      FxButton(
                          padding: FxSpacing.xy(16, 12),
                          onPressed: () {
                            controller.register();
                          },
                          backgroundColor: customTheme.card,
                          splashColor:
                              theme.colorScheme.onBackground.withAlpha(40),
                          elevation: 0,
                          borderRadiusAll: 4,
                          child: Row(
                            children: [
                              Image(
                                image: AssetImage(Images.google),
                                height: 17,
                                width: 17,
                              ),
                              FxSpacing.width(20),
                              FxText.l2(
                                'Login with Google',
                                fontWeight: 600,
                                color: theme.colorScheme.onBackground,
                              ),
                            ],
                          )),
                      FxSpacing.width(20),
                      Expanded(
                        child: FxButton(
                          padding: FxSpacing.y(12),
                          onPressed: () {
                            controller.register();
                          },
                          backgroundColor: customTheme.fitnessPrimary,
                          elevation: 0,
                          borderRadiusAll: 4,
                          child: FxText.b2(
                            'Continue',
                            color: customTheme.fitnessOnPrimary,
                            fontWeight: 600,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  FxSpacing.height(20),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      FxText.b3(
                        'Already have an account? ',
                      ),
                      InkWell(
                          onTap: () {
                            controller.goToLogInScreen();
                          },
                          child: FxText.b3(
                            'Log In',
                            color: customTheme.fitnessPrimary,
                          )),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
        });
  }
}
```

Any help appreciated

Comment: in UI you want if the email or password is wrong then it shows in the red colour text below textformfield?

Comment: could you use snackbar if login failed

Comment: I'm hoping to have it have a popup saying what went wrong in the UI, i am just not sure how to do this

Comment: whatis `FxTextStyle` is it any ui dart package or classs

Comment: Its a class, it shouldn't affect what I'm needing to do

Comment: colud you provide that class .then i can easily help you.

Comment: add key to `scaffold` widget .use insid false condition `globalkey.currentState
            ?.showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text("login failed")));`